# SVG image is not showing properly in mobile phone

Tags: html, css, image, svg, mobile

On the monitor display changing the width (desktop, tablet and mobile) the SVG image is showing perfect but on the real mobile phone the image is truncated.
You can see by opening the repository on real phone: https://miorita69.github.io/perle_di_stelle/

In the header I am using picture tag. All the three stages on the computer monitor are showing perfect, but the third in the mobile phone is trancated.

```
<picture>
   <source type="image/svg+xml" media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="images/logo_desktop.svg">
   <source type="image/svg+xml" media="(min-width: 680px)" srcset="images/logo_tablet.svg">
   <source type="image/svg+xml" media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="images/logo_mobile.svg">
   <img class="navbar__logo-image" src="images/logo-mobile.png" alt="Logo Perle di Stelle">
</picture>
```

CSS

```
.navbar__logo-image {
   width: auto;
   height: calc(90% - 10px);
   display: block;
   margin: 5px auto;
}

 @media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:860px) {
 .navbar__logo-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--tablet-navbar-height);
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*border: blue 1px solid;*/
 }
 ...
}
```

Can You help me to identify the problem with SVG image in mobile phone.

P.S. I know that Android earlier 3 are not supporting SVG images. I tested with Android 9.0 version and does not show perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your SVGs are using `<text>` elements.  So proper rendering of the SVGs rely on the device, that they are being displayed on, having the specified fonts available.

- In the case of logo_desktop.svg, most of the text has been converted to paths, so the problem is not really showing up.
- In logo_mobile.svg and logo_tablet.svg, however, most or all of the text is `<text>` elements using the "Monotype Corsiva" font. It's a low probability that any devices will have that font installed.

You have a few solutions, in order of my recommendation:

1. Go back into your vector editor and make sure **all** text elements are converted to paths.  Your problem will disappear.
2. License the Microsoft Cursiva font and add it to your website CSS using `@font-face` etc.
3. Change the SVGs to use a font that all devices are likely to support. Ie. plain old default `font: serif`.

Comment: I've found this comment via an AI generated search result, which suggested "Microsoft Cursiva" font as a solution to an SVG rendering issue I have. This is the only instance of these two words together I can find via google. Is this a typo? A genuine thing? Or an attempt to feed false data into AI? Thanks for taking the time to respond.